# How to avoid "Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840" in Swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift

I keep getting this particular error when trying to parse a JSON response in Swift:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No value." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No value.}

Code:

```
    let dict = [
        "phone": phone,
        "firstname": "\(String(describing: firstName))",
        "lastname": "\(String(describing: lastName))"
        ]
        as [String: Any]

    if let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict, options: []) {

        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "\(config.baseURL)employee")!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.httpBody = jsonData
        request.timeoutInterval = 30.0

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in

            if error != nil {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.alertController.singleButtonAlertController("Error", (error?.localizedDescription)!, self, self.defaultAction)
                    return
                }
            }

            guard let data_ = data else {
                return
            }

            do {
                let jsonObj = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data_, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

                guard let parseJSON = jsonObj else {
                    return
                }

                self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.rightBarButton


                let meta = parseJSON["meta"] as? [String:Any]
                let status = meta!["status"] as? String


                if status == "200" {
                    isEmployeeModified = true
                    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

                } else {
                    let info = meta!["info"] as? String
                    let message = meta!["message"] as? String
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {

                        self.alertController.singleButtonAlertController(info!, message!, self, self.defaultAction)
                    }
                }

            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
```

I have used similar codes in other parts of the project and everything checks out.

Comment: add the error message with stacktrace

Comment: And also tell us where the error is occurring.

Comment: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No value." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No value.}

Comment: `No value` means the returned string is empty. By the way why do you assign `mutableContainers` to an immutable `let` constant. And don't use `NSDictionary` in Swift. You are fighting the strong type system.

Comment: ... and the syntax `"\(String(describing: firstName))"` is horrible. `firstName` is most likely a string. You are creating a `String` from a `String` and then again another `String` with String Interpolation. I wish the compiler would throw an error when parsing that nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

According to this Error, the response from your server is not a valid `JSON`
Can you use `responseString` instead of `responseJSON` like below

```
 Alamofire.request(URL, method: requestMethod, parameters: params).responseString{ response in
    print(response)
}
```

Comment: But the response from the server is a valid JSON, here:

{
    "meta": {
        "status": "200",
        "message": "Successful",
        "info": "Request processed successfully"
    }
}

Comment: If you are getting response correctly and your request processed successfully then how you have this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out what was wrong and I'm going to explain this here for future readers. Apparently, I was doing a GET request the wrong way, so when I intend to do a POST request, for some reason, it still sees it as a GET request and that was why I kept getting the response: **Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No value." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No value.}**

Below is my refactored code and it works without any hassle:

```
    let dict = [
        "phone": phone,
        "firstname": firstName,
        "lastname": lastName
        ] as [String : Any]

    guard let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict, options: []) else {
        return
    }

    guard let url = URL(string: "\(config.baseURL)employee") else {
        return
    }

    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.httpBody = jsonData as Data
    request.timeoutInterval = 10

    let session = URLSession.shared
    session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

        if let response = response {
            print("JSON Response: \(response)")
        }

        if error != nil {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.rightBarButton
                self.alertController.singleButtonAlertController("Error", (error?.localizedDescription)!, self, self.defaultAction)
                return
            }
        }

        if let data = data {
            do {
                let parseJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? NSDictionary

                let meta = parseJSON!["meta"] as? [String:Any]
                let status = meta!["status"] as? String


                if status == "200" {
                    isEmployeeModified = true
                    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

                } else {
                    let info = meta!["info"] as? String
                    let message = meta!["message"] as? String
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.alertController.singleButtonAlertController(info!, message!, self, self.defaultAction)
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }.resume()
```